# Is my VM using KVM or QEMU?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

After installing Ubuntu 11.10 and copying my KVM images which were created on Ubuntu 11.04 over to the new system, I notice that Virt-manager says it's using QEMU and not KVM. Also when running `virsh version` it says `Running hypervisor: QEMU 0.14.1`.

However, when I run `kvm-ok` it says `INFO: /dev/kvm exists` and `KVM acceleration can be used`. Also, the XML file of my VM clearly states it should use KVM: `<domain type='kvm'>`
 `<emulator>/usr/bin/kvm</emulator>`.

Furthermore, `lsmod |grep kvm` shows the following (when the VM is running):

```
kvm_intel              61643  3
kvm                   383822  1 kvm_intel
```

So how do I know if KVM or QEMU is being used? And why am I getting such contradictory output of these different commands?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because kvm builds on top of QEMU, it's just a hw acceleration.

With this you can see that the actual process running your VM is a kvm process.

```
ps xa| grep "[b]in/kvm"
```

Comment: Fantastic, that clearly shows I'm really using KVM. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine#Design

> By itself, KVM does not perform any emulation. Instead, a user-space program uses the /dev/kvm interface to set up the guest VM's address space, feeds it simulated I/O and maps its video display back onto the host's. QEMU versions 0.10.0 and later make use of this.